# Proportional resize images in a fixed block

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have 3 random images and one fixed block (200x300px).

Please, help me to write an algoritm, I need to change image size proportionally to get into fixed block.

Images width must be equal of block width

http://jsfiddle.net/U8AAu/2/

```
var images = [
    getRandSizes(),
    getRandSizes(),
    getRandSizes()
];

var sizes = getProportionalSizes(200, 300, images);

$.each(sizes, function(i, size){
    var $img = $("<div>", {
        class: 'img',
        width: size[0],
        height: size[1]
    }).appendTo('.fixed-block')
});

// todo:
function getProportionalSizes(maxWidth, maxHeight, sizes){
    return sizes;
}

function getRandSizes(){
    return [getRand(100,200), getRand(100,200)]
}

function getRand(min, max) {    
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always changing the image width to fill the box width will cause aspect ratio issues, and will distort your pictures. I would recommend doing something like this.

```
var image1 = new Object( );
var sizeArray = getRandSizes( );
image1.width = sizeArray[0];
image1.height = sizeArray[1]; //Repeat for images 2 and 3

var images = 
[
    image1,
    image2,
    image3
];

images = getProportionalSizes( 200, 300, images );

images.forEach( function( image )
{
    var $img = $("<div>", 
    {
        class: 'img',
        width: image.width,
        height: image.height
    }).appendTo('.fixed-block')
});

function getProportionalSizes(maxWidth, maxHeight, images)
{
    var totalHeight;

    images.forEach( function( image )
    {
        totalHeight += image.height;
    });

    images.forEach( function( image )
    {
        var ratio = image.height / totalHeight;
        image.height *= ratio;
        image.width *= ratio; //This will ensure that images maintain aspect ratio, but that the total height of the 3 images matches the container height.
    });

    return images;
}

function getRandSizes()
{
    return [getRand(100,200), getRand(100,200)]
}

function getRand(min, max)
{    
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

EDIT ------------------------
If having full block width is a requirement, and the distortion of the images is irrelevant, then do this instead.

```
function getProportionalSizes(maxWidth, maxHeight, images)
{
    var totalHeight;

    images.forEach( function( image )
    {
        totalHeight += image.height;
    });

    images.forEach( function( image )
    {
        var ratio = image.height / totalHeight;
        image.height *= ratio;
        image.width = maxWidth //This will keep the individual image height proportional to each other, but stretch the picture in the x-direction to fill the block.
    });

    return images;
}
```

Comment: Let me know how this works for you, tried my best but got sidetracked in the middle so my thoughts might be kind of disjointed.

Comment: Edited to make a minor fix, accidental use of var  in front of images.foreach( when creating the divs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not a solution. Image width must be equal of block width

Comment: Wont this distort your pictures by changing the aspect ratio? And if you want them to be equal to the block width, should the total height still be equal to the block height? If so, instead of multiplying 'image.width *= ratio;' You would just do 'image.width = maxWidth;' This will keep the image height proportional, and then stretch the image width.

Comment: Images must fill block. For height - too. Small images do not fill the block.

Comment: If you change `image.height *= ratio;` to `image.height = ratio * maxHeight;`, this should fill your block.

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, I think you used the wrong array element for height, when you are calculating your ratio, you are doing the width / totalHeight, whereas it should be height / totalHeight

Comment: @beaker since you acquire the ratio by doing image.height/maxHeight, doing image.height = ratio * maxHeight will just return your image to its original height.

Comment: This fiddle update, by removing the bottom margin and changing the typo on the ratio calc, works. http://jsfiddle.net/U8AAu/9/ ( There is a 1pixel gap on the bottom, this happened due to rounding issues )

Comment: @PugsOverDrugs ratio is `image.height / totalHeight` i.e., proportion of the current image height to the height of all of the original images stacked. If you then multiply it by the height of the box we're trying to fit into, `maxHeight`, you get the correct answer. Though possibly with rounding errors :)

Comment: @beaker ahh, yes, touche, Good call :P

Answer (score 0):

To change the width of the image to a fixed block width of 200, change your size definition to:

```
      width: 200,
      height: size[1]*200/size[0]
```

This will preserve the aspect ratio while resizing the image to the proper width.

Note that it is possible that the resulting image will be taller than the height specified. If the original image is `100x200`, the resulting resized image will be `200x400`. This is unavoidable, given the problem constraints.

Comment: It's decision for one image... How to change  3+ images?

Comment: Please be more precise. In what way do you want to change 3+ images? Do you want them all to have the same width? Do you want them all to be scaled by the same amount?

Comment: Images width must be equal with block width and sum of images heights must be equal with block height

Comment: And height of the images should be changed proportionally

Comment: Your two statements are contradictory: Should the width of each image equal the block width, or must the width of each image be proportional to the widths of the other images? Though it sounds like the answer given by PugsOverDrugs with the aspect ratio distortion is what you're looking for.

Comment: Height of each image be proportional to the heights of the other images

Comment: In decision of PugsOverDrugs, images do not fill for height block